# Collision between camera and objects in A-Frame 1.2.0

Tags: javascript, camera, collision-detection, aframe, webxr

I'm developing a game with the latest Aframe version 1.2.0 and I'm having a problem.
How to manage collisions between the camera and objects?
When I approach an object, I cross it. Where other versions handled collisions, for this one I can't find anything.
I've tried a lot of things but nothing works.
I think I have the beginning of a solution with the aframe-physics-system.min.js library
but I can only manage dynamic objects and not static objects.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Did you get it to work in V 1.2.0?

Answer (score 0):

For restricting the movements of the player/camera, it's generally recommended to use a nav mesh rather than a physics system.

See notes and links here:

https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/misc#kinematic-body-deprecated

https://www.donmccurdy.com/2017/08/20/creating-a-nav-mesh-for-a-webvr-scene/

https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-inspector-plugin-recast