# In Aframe,how do I make it so objects can prevent me from moving any further into them when colliding with them?

Tags: three.js, 3d, collision-detection, aframe

So I'm an 11th grader who is currently learning how to use Aframe for software engineering class and I'm trying to experiment with the coding playground that Aframe officially gave me.I want to make it so when I move into the box from the app, the box won't let me move inside it (and also,the box won't move when I move into it).I've tried SOME documents for collision detection in aframe,but I don't think any of them really give me what I'm looking for.Is there anyone that can help me with what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do what you are trying to do would be to use a NavMesh.

Some links here:

[Collision between camera and objects in A-Frame 1.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69705229/collision-between-camera-and-objects-in-a-frame-1-2-0/69868484#69868484)

Comment: Yeah,the documents are saying that I would need something like blender for this one,which is a problem because I'm gonna be spending some work with my school chromebook which,very likely,wouldn't be able to run blender

Comment: There's another web-based option that doesn't use blender, covered in this link:
https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-inspector-plugin-recast